# Overlapping images - how to slice in photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, page-layout

I got pretty simple example of site layout (link below), and i need to slice it.
The problem is, when i have 2 images, or image and title overlapping, and when i try to make slices of both, i get one of the images cut into 3 or more parts. Which is not good. Is there a way to make slices overlap? So i get each image in one part?

[image: image of some simple, overlapping layout]

Comment: I wouldn't use Photoshop's slice tool for web design. Export the images in full and position them with CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing is pretty unnecessary in most cases since browsers support Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

CSS allows you to specify and image as a background for an html element. This is **far** more efficient than sling up some image and then placing pieces in various table cells or block elements to reconstruct them.

CSS also allows you to very easily overlay live text over background images.

Unless there is some mandatory reason you *must* slice an image, I wouldn't.

Comment: Well, I got requested to use slices, but it's so bad it cuts everything into small pieces, i resigned from the idea, and just did as you said. Thanks

Comment: Clients, or those unaware of how web sites are built in modern times may request things using "buzzwords" just to sound like they are a bit knowledgable. It's not uncommon. However, if you know your stuff, as I'm sure you do, you should ignore such comments. After all, you would never build a web page using a bunch of `<font></font>`, `<b></b>`, `<marquee></marquee>`, or `<center></center>` tags now.